# Gamepad vibration detection on Windows

Tags: windows, software-development, game-development, device-driver

Is there any way you can detect when gamepad using Xinput driver on Windows starts vibrating/rumbling (when playing a game for example)? I just need any kind of the output data as state, so i can later use it in my applications. Are there any software or code libraries that allow to do that?